# access controls on a asp.net master page from child page

Tags: asp.net

i want to access a span on a asp.net master page from child page, so i'd made a public property on that master page-->

```
 public partial class Ui_MasterPage_UI : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        public int tax = 0;

        public string notification
        {
            set
            {
                (this.FindControl("notification") as HtmlAnchor).InnerText = value.ToString();
            }
        }
       ------------------//some code
    }
```

and now wants to access this from a child page to set some text into that htmlanchor tag,

so that i'd written some script-->

**child page**

```
public partial class Ui_ProductDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void ListView_ProductDetails_itemcommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Master.notification = "some text";            ////////showing error
 ------------------//some code       
    }
------------------//some code       
}
```

but getting the syntax error
i think there is some problem in above code,,,,,so plz review it......
is there any other way to do this ???
thnku

Comment: Frazell is correct read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h(v=vs.80).aspx for explanation, examples and details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the Page.Master property to the type of your Master Page.

```
((Ui_MasterPage_UI)Page.Master).Notification = "some text";
```